# Java path problems on Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

I'm trying to compile a Java project under Cygwin using a native Win32 Java.

The Java binaries are correctly found under `/cygdrive/c/jdk/bin` on my machine.

The following command works fine:

```
javac -d . ./gnu/kawa/util/PreProcess.java
```

The `PreProcess.class` file is generated in `./gnu/kawa/util/`. Trying to invoke Java on this fails however:

```
CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH java gnu.kawa.util.PreProcess \
   %java6 +use:com.sun.net.httpserver +enable:XML \
   `sed -e 's|\([^ ]*\)|./\1|' < ./patch-source-list`
Error: Could not find or load main class gnu.kawa.util.PreProcess
...
```

This command was invoked by `make`, that's where the `$CLASSPATH` variable is set dynamically. `patch-source-list` is just a list of class names. The `:` in the classpath looks suspicious, but I'm not sure how to test `;` while not annoying `sh`.

My only other suspicion is that the native Java is trying `gnu\kawa\util\PreProcess`, but I think cygwin can transparently handle that.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try with `CLASSPATH='.;'$CLASSPATH`

Comment: Thank you, Mat! That was the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to build your path using the ':' and then fix the results using cygpath.  This is probably overkill in your specific situation, but in a general case where you may have references to multiple directories, some of which may be referenced as absolute rather than relative paths, or if you are working with cygwin symlinks, it is much more useful.

```
$ ln -s /cygdrive/c/development/libraries/ ../libs
$ cygpath -pw /cygdrive/c/development/:.:../libs
C:\development\;.;C:\development\libraries\
```

so then you'd build your CLASSPATH variable as before, and in the final stage run

```
CLASSPATH="`cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH"`" java (whatever)
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember, the JVM has no idea that you are using the cygwin bash shell.

Two things:

1. for the classpath locations, use the windows path names. Thus, no *"/cygdrive/c/somepath"*, but *"c:\somepath\"*  ("/" and "\" can be used interchangeably however)
2. use ';' instead of ':' in the classpath list

This should work:

```
export CLASSPATH="./gnu/kawa/util/PreProcess.class"
CLASSPATH=".;$CLASSPATH" java gnu.kawa.util.PreProcess
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `:` in the classpath looks suspicious, but I'm not sure how to test `;` while not annoying `sh`.

You're exactly right: you need to use `;` instead of `:`. As for how to use it — as Mat alludes to above, you need to ["quote"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) the semicolon. Any of these will work:

```
CLASSPATH=.\;$CLASSPATH java Foo

CLASSPATH=.';'$CLASSPATH java Foo

CLASSPATH='.;'$CLASSPATH java Foo

CLASSPATH=".;$CLASSPATH" java Foo
```

You can use whichever one you like best. (The first uses a backslash, which quotes a single following character. The second and third use single-quotes, which quote a sequence of zero or more characters. The fourth uses double-quotes, which are like single-quotes except that they still allow the variable `$CLASSPATH` to be expanded. For that matter, you could also write something like

```
CLASSPATH=".;"$CLASSPATH java Foo
```

if you want. See the above link for lots more information about quoting in Bash.)